# Uploadify bug with Ember on Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, ember.js, uploadify

I have an ember project which allows the user to upload pictures using the [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) library. Everything works great on every browsers **except IE**.

[image: Screenshot of the ember image uploader]

The user needs to **double click** to open the file dialog instead of just **one simple** click.

I have been investigating this issue to know what was conflicting with what. It appears that the problem occurs only when using any version of **ember with jquery in a version higher than 1.8.1**.

Does anyone encountered this issue or have an idea for how to fix it?

Comment: providing a jsbin example would really help people get started.  You can use emberjs.jsbin.com as a starting point.